# difference between kernel mode and user mode caching in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-8, http.sys

What is the difference between kernel mode caching and user mode caching and how to track both ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Kernal Mode caching is essentially going to handle caching requests at the OS-level, so contents that are stored in it can be accessed without ever going down the rest of the usual pipeline (i.e. it will not have to go down to the ASP.NET or IIS-level caches to check for the contents) :

[image]

So the request hits the initial cache (http.sys), finds what it needs and sends it back, all without ever having to proceed further down the pipeline.

As a the result of this, it's usually quite fast. A limitation of it however is that it does not support many user-level features such as authentication and authorization, so it may not fit all scenarios.

User-mode on the other hand is going to fill in the gaps where Kernal-mode cannot be used, which primarily surrounds authorized/authenticated content (as it requires a check to see if the user can actually access the contents), but there are [many other scenarios](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817445) that could cause the `http.sys` cache to not be used.

With regards to actually checking to see if content is or is not being cached (and possibly why), you can use FREB (Failed Request Event Buffering). The following command can be used to find out which content is cached in kernel mode:

```
netsh http show cachestate
```

Comment: Thanks Rion for your reply , now I got a bit understanding of the difference between those two .

Comment: sorry, but it is not clear to me what is the difference from one to the other. They are both cached on the server side, on the client side, or where? I thought that the question was about what it differs, not in which case one would be used or the other. There is a graphic explaining kernel-mode, but not one for user-mode. Sorry for my english, might it sound rude sometimes, is not my intention.